# reading the next line in a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the next line data from a text file. 
For example a text file abc contains:

Test Results : Fail
Error Code : 2000-0333

I need to search for keyword "Test Results : Fail" and if it exists, the data "2000-0333" should be stored in a variable.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
   List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt").ToList<string();
   for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
   {
       if (filecontents[i].Contains("Test Results : Fail"))
       {                          
           //need to get the data here
       }
   }
```

Could I please get solution to this??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your next line, will be in filecontents[i + 1]

```
List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt").ToList<string();
for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
   {
       if (filecontents[i].Contains("Test Results : Fail"))
       {                          
           string error = filecontents[i + 1];
       }
   }
```

Take care, if the last string is of the file is "Test Results : Fail", when try to get filecontents[i + 1] will throw an exception.

To get the 2000-0333, you should split the string error by the ":"

```
string errorNumber = filecontents[i + 1].Split(':')[1]
```

But, if there is no ':' it will throw an exception. Be aware of that.

You can .Trim() the errorNumber, to know for sure there is no blank space in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt").ToList<string();
for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
{
    if (filecontents[i].Contains("Test Results : Fail"))
    {                          
       string s = fileContents[i+1].Split(" : ")[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(  (from c in filecontents where c.Contains("Test Results : Fail") select filecontents.IndexOf(c)).Any())
{
    int index = (from c in filecontents where c.Contains("Test Results : Fail") select filecontents.IndexOf(c)).SingleOrDefault();
     string error = filecontents[index + 1];
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would never encourage this type of code even if it's technically correct. It's difficult to read, more complicated to debug than it needs to be, and opens up multiple points of failure.